# Closed form for integral of $\lfloor x \rfloor$?

Tags: definite-integrals

Is there a closed form for $$\int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x}dx$$

I found ln$(2)$ as my answer for n=1 from my calculator, but not sure how to find the general solution.

Comment: Is $n$ always an integer?

Comment: Do you mean $\int_n^{n+1}\frac nx\,dx$?

Comment: If $n$ is an positive integer the integral is $n\int^{n+1}_n\frac{1}{x}\,dx=n\log(1+\tfrac1n)$

Comment: Note that $\lfloor x \rfloor = n$ almost everywhere between $n$ and $n+1$.

Comment: If $n$ is not an integer, start from @OliverDiaz 's answer, but split the integral into two parts, at the integer between $n$ and $n+1$

Comment: We also have the asymptotic formula $$ \begin{align}
\scriptsize\int_0^x\frac{\lfloor t\rfloor}t\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\scriptsize x-\frac12\log(2\pi x)-\frac{6\{x\}^2-6\{x\}+1}{12x}-\frac{2\{x\}^3-3\{x\}^2+\{x\}}{12x^2}-\frac{30\{x\}^4-60\{x\}^3+30\{x\}^2-1}{360x^3}\\
&\phantom{\ =}\scriptsize-\frac{6\{x\}^5-15\{x\}^4+10\{x\}^3-\{x\}}{120x^4}+\underbrace{\int_x^\infty\frac{6\{t\}^5-15\{t\}^4+10\{t\}^3-\{t\}}{30t^5}\,\mathrm{d}t}_{O\left(x^{-5}\right)}\\
\end{align} $$ where $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n > 1$:

$$\begin{align}\int_n^{n+1}\frac {\lfloor x \rfloor} xdx&= \int_n^{\lfloor n+1 \rfloor}\frac {\lfloor x \rfloor} xdx+\int_{\lfloor n+1 \rfloor}^{n+1}\frac {\lfloor x \rfloor} xdx \\&=\int_n^{\lfloor n+1 \rfloor}\frac {\lfloor n \rfloor} xdx+\int_{\lfloor n+1 \rfloor}^{n+1}\frac {\lfloor n+1 \rfloor} xdx \\&= \lfloor n\rfloor\int_n^{\lfloor n+1 \rfloor}\frac 1 xdx+\lfloor n+1 \rfloor\int_{\lfloor n+1 \rfloor}^{n+1}\frac 1 xdx \\~\\&=\lfloor n \rfloor(\ln\lfloor n+1 \rfloor - \ln n) + \lfloor n+1 \rfloor(\ln (n+1)-\ln \lfloor n+1 \rfloor)\\~\\&=\lfloor n+1 \rfloor\ln(n+1)-\ln \lfloor n+1 \rfloor-\lfloor n \rfloor\ln n\end{align}$$

which reduces to the other answers when $n$ is an integer.

Comment: The second line should be
$$\int_n^{\lfloor n \rfloor + 1} \frac {\lfloor n \rfloor} x dx +
 \int_{\lfloor n \rfloor + 1}^{n + 1} \frac {\lfloor n \rfloor + 1} x dx.$$

Comment: Indeed.${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $n$ is an integer, $\lfloor x \rfloor = n$ throughout the range of integration (except at the right endpoint), so this is just

$$\int_n^{n+1} \frac nx ~ dx = n \ln \frac{n+1}{n} = \ln \left( 1+\frac 1n \right)^n.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is an integer, then $\lfloor x\rfloor=n$ for $x\in [n,n+1)$. Thus
$$\int_n^{n+1} \frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x}\ dx = \int_n^{n+1} \frac{n}{x}\ dx = n\int_n^{n+1} \frac{1}{x}\ dx.$$

At this point, I will let you consider if anything special happens for $n=0$, or if $n<0$, but for positive $n$, you get
$$ = n\left(\ln(n+1) - \ln(n)\right) = n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right).$$